# How to enforce GET request using urllib.urlopen?

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7, urllib, yodlee

```
account_summary_API_url = "https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/account/summary/all"

account_summary_params = urllib.urlencode({'cobrandSessionToken':cobSessionToken,'userSessionToken':userSessionToken})

account_summary_response = urllib.urlopen(account_summary_API_url,account_summary_params).read()
```

I am using above url then encoded params to call the API but this API needs to be called with GET method . How do I enforce that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urllib.urlopen("http://yoururl.com/?%s" % your_url_encoded_params)
```

Passing the params by way of the url makes this a GET request.

So:

```
account_summary_response = urllib.urlopen("%s?%s" % (account_summary_API_url,account_summary_params)).read()
```

Comment: Then what it would be for a POST request ?

Comment: What you have above, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html which specifies "the optional data argument may be given to specify a POST request"